# Gostaria de saber porque este código em Javascript não está funcionando (programa simples)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-eventos, eventos-do-mouse

```js
var verificador = document.window.getElementById('input#verificador');
var nacionalidade = document.window.getElementById('div#nacionalidade');

function verificar() {

  if (verificador == 'brasil' || verificador == 'BRASIL' || verificador == 'Brasil') {
    nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é brasileiro';

  } else {

    nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é estrangeiro';

  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Teste de nacionalidade</h1>
  Digite o país que você nasceu:<input type="text" name="verificador" id="verificador" />
  <input type="button" value="Clique e descubra sua nacionalidade " onclick="verificar()" />
  <div id="nacionalidade">Nacionalidade</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Observação: se o id do elemento é `verificador`, você deve usar `getElementById('verificador')`. O valor `'input#verificador'` faria sentido apenas se utilizar com o `querySelector`.

Comment: Dito isso, o que deveria ser `document.window`?

Answer (score 5):

Seu código está com vários erros, nessa linha está errado.

```
var verificador = document.window.getElementById('input#verificador');
var nacionalidade = document.window.getElementById('div#nacionalidade');
```

Você não pode colocar o `window` depois de `document` e o `getElementById` não pode selecionar seletores que nem o `querySelector` ele só aceita o nome do `id`.

```
var verificador = window.document.getElementById('verificador');
var nacionalidade = window.document.getElementById('nacionalidade');
```

E na parte do `if` você não está comparando o `value` que é o valor do `input` com `id="verificador"`

```
if (verificador == 'brasil' || verificador == 'BRASIL' || verificador == 'Brasil') 
{
   nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é brasileiro';

}
```

É só colocar o `value` na frente de `verificador`.

```
if (verificador.value == 'brasil' || verificador.value == 'BRASIL' || verificador.value == 'Brasil')
{
   nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é brasileiro';

}
```

Pronto! era só isso, agora está funcionando perfeitamente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Teste de nacionalidade</h1>
    Digite o país que você nasceu:<input type="text" name="verificador" id="verificador"/>
    <input type="button" value="Clique e descubra sua nacionalidade " onclick="verificar()"/>
    <div id="nacionalidade">Nacionalidade</div>


<script>
 
    var verificador = window.document.getElementById('verificador');
    var nacionalidade = window.document.getElementById('nacionalidade');
    
    function verificar() {
        
        if (verificador.value == 'brasil' || verificador.value == 'BRASIL' || verificador.value == 'Brasil') {
            nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é brasileiro';
        } else {
            nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é estrangeiro';
        }
    }
           
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alguns erros:

- o `getElementById` quer somente a ID, como tens `input#verificador` é um seletor de CSS completo e pode funcionar por exemplo com o `querySelector``
- usa somente document e não `document.window``
- usa `.value` para extrair o valor do input
- coloquei os `var` dentro da função para evitar casos em que o JavaScript é lido antes do HTML ser interpretado. Assim fica também mais encapsulado
- usei o `.toLowerCase` para aceitar letras grandes e pequenas

```js
function verificar() {
  var verificador = document.getElementById('verificador').value;
  var nacionalidade = document.getElementById('nacionalidade');
  if (verificador.toLowerCase() == 'brasil') {
    nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é brasileiro';
  } else {
    nacionalidade.innerText = 'Você é estrangeiro';
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Teste de nacionalidade</h1>
Digite o país que você nasceu:<input type="text" name="verificador" id="verificador" />
<input type="button" value="Clique e descubra sua nacionalidade " onclick="verificar()" />
<div id="nacionalidade">Nacionalidade</div>
```